# Convert comma separated numbers to corresponding text

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a spreadsheet with a column that lists references numerically in the following form "1, 2, 6" for example. I also have a separate table which correlates the number to an actual reference:

[image: References]

Is there a way to convert this numbered list to the corresponding text list?
For example, "1, 2, 6" would be translated to "Package Insert/Mfr, Trissel's 18th edition, USP 797"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update: Add Vba**

If Key Assumption #1 down below is not to your liking, you can try this snippet of code.

```
Function lookupStringCodes(lookupValue As Range, lookupRange As Range, lookupResult As Range)

Dim commaSepVals() As String
    commaSepVals = Split(CStr(lookupValue.Value), ",")

Dim output As String
    output = vbNullString

For i = LBound(commaSepVals) To UBound(commaSepVals)
    commaSepVals(i) = Replace(commaSepVals(i), " ", "")
Next

Dim sep As String
    sep = ", "


For j = LBound(commaSepVals) To UBound(commaSepVals)
    output = output & _
    Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(lookupResult, _
    Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(CStr(commaSepVals(j)), lookupRange, 0))

    If j < UBound(commaSepVals) Then
        output = output & sep
    End If

Next

lookupStringCodes = output


End Function
```

Which you can call like so:

[image]

**Original Answer: Worksheet Function**

Key assumptions:

1. You only ever have 3 integers like in your example, ranging from 1...n (if this is not true and you can have more than 3 integers, it's much easier to just solve this using VBA unless you want to split this text to columns)
2. You want this done in one formula, instead of using text to columns

Try the following:

```
=VLOOKUP(LEFT(A2,(FIND(",",A2,1)-1)), G$2:H$11, 2, FALSE) & ", " & VLOOKUP(LEFT(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2," ",REPT(" ", 100)),100,100)), LEN(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2," ",REPT(" ", 100)),100,100)))-1), G$2:H$11, 2, FALSE) & ", "& VLOOKUP(TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A2," ",REPT(" ",LEN(A2))),LEN(A2))), G$2:H$11, 2, FALSE)
```

Formatted to be easier to read:

```
=VLOOKUP(LEFT(A2,(FIND(",",A2,1)-1)), G$2:H$11, 2, FALSE) & ", " & 
VLOOKUP(LEFT(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2," ",REPT(" ", 100)),100,100)),
LEN(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2," ",REPT(" ", 100)),100,100)))-1), G$2:H$11, 2, FALSE) & ", "& 
VLOOKUP(TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A2," ",REPT(" ",LEN(A2))),LEN(A2))), G$2:H$11, 2, FALSE)
```

Basically: Take the text to the left of the first comma, look it up in your lookup table. Then, take the text between the first space and the second comma, look it up in your lookup table. Finally, take the text to the right of the last space, look it up in your lookup table.

Replace G2:H11 with your lookup table. Replace A2 with your starting value. [image]